# Java - numerical base calculator (ie base 10 to base 5)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a calculator that calculates and converts numbers from varying bases. Now i believe this has a really small problem but I cant find it for the life of me.Here is the code:

```
package basecalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("num?");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    int numLen = String.valueOf(number).length();

    int[] res = new int[numLen];

    toIntArr(number, res);

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println(toBase10(res));

}

public static void toIntArr(int n, int [] res){
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    while(n > 0) {
        stack.push(n % 10);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; !stack.isEmpty(); i++) {
        res[i] = stack.pop();
    }
}

public static int toBase10(int [] res) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = res.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += res[i] * Math.pow(10, i); //here is where it freaks out. 
    }

    return sum;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
run:
num?
456
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at basecalculator.BaseCalculator.toBase10(BaseCalculator.java:49)
at basecalculator.BaseCalculator.main(BaseCalculator.java:28)
4 5 6 Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Can anyone identify the problem?

Comment: no, all from netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this:

```
for (int i = res.length; i >= 0; i--)
```

to:

```
for (int i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
                        ^^^
```

**Why**?

Arrays are *zero-based* in Java. So, for example, if you have array of size **10**, the indexes will be **0, 1, 2 ... 9**.

So if you'll try to reach `array[10]` (which is the `.length` of the array) you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: If he tries to get the value in `res.length` he'll get an exception, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ahhh ok. thanks man. all these indexes confuse the hell out of me. that was all it needed :D

Comment: I mean, you just say *do this* but don't add any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `i` in your `for (int i = 0; !stack.isEmpty(); i++)` in `toIntArr` is greater or equals than `res.length`. Change the validation to

```
for (int i = 0; i < res.length && !stack.isEmpty(); i++) {
    //...
}
```

Also, in your `toBase10` method, you need to change the upper bound for `i` variable:

```
for (int i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //...
}
```